# Using compare operator with two different classes objects

Tags: c++, class, operator-keyword

I have a problem with operators. Generally I know basics of using operators. But my problem starts when I want to compare two objects. I have 2 different classes declaration files okrag.h and prostokat.h . I want to compare two objects from different classes:

```
//okrag.h   -- circle class
#ifndef __OKRAG_H__
#define __OKRAG_H__
#include "figura.h"
#include "prostokat.h"

class COkrag: public CFigura
{
    protected:
    int m_iR; 

    public:
        COkrag();
        COkrag(int x, int y, int r);
        ~COkrag();
        void ZmienR(int r);
        float PodajObwod();
        float PodajPole();  
        int PodajR();
        void operator+(int r);
        friend void operator+(COkrag o, int x[2]);


        bool operator>(COkrag o2);

        friend bool operator>(COkrag o1, CProstokat o2);

        bool operator<(COkrag o2);
        bool operator>=(COkrag o2);
        bool operator<=(COkrag o2);
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream &wy, COkrag &O);

};
#endif



//prostokat.h
#ifndef __PROSTOKAT_H__
#define __PROSTOKAT_H__
#include "figura.h"
#include "okrag.h"

class CProstokat: public CFigura
{
    protected:
    int m_iSz, m_iWy; 


    public:
        CProstokat();
        CProstokat(int x, int y, int szer, int wys);
        ~CProstokat();
        void ZmienSz(int x);
        void ZmienWy(int y);
        float PodajObwod();
        float PodajPole();
        void operator+(int a);
        friend void operator+(CProstokat p, int x[2]);

        bool operator>(CProstokat p2);
        bool operator<(CProstokat p2);
        bool operator>=(CProstokat p2);
        bool operator<=(CProstokat p2);


        friend ostream& operator << (ostream &wy, CProstokat &P);

};
#endif
```

My problem is when it starts compiling and and finds this line: `friend bool operator>(COkrag o1, CProstokat o2);`

It says: `Error 1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CProstokat'`

I have no idea what the reason is. It looks like it doesn't know object CProstokat but header file with declaration of this class was included.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

EDIT:
I have corrected my code and here is what I get. I don't know why I couldn't add const to `bool operator>(CProstokat & p2);` I wanted it to look like this:

`bool operator>(CProstokat & p2);`

but compiler says

`Error  3   error C2662: 'CProstokat::PodajPole' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const CProstokat' to 'CProstokat &'`

Now it works without it. Here is what I get.

```
#ifndef __OKRAG_H__
#define __OKRAG_H__
#include "figura.h"


class CProstokat;

class COkrag: public CFigura
{
    protected:
    int m_iR; 

    public:
        COkrag();
        COkrag(int x, int y, int r);
        ~COkrag();
        void ZmienR(int r);
        float PodajObwod();
        float PodajPole();  
        int PodajR();
        void operator+(int r);
        friend void operator+(COkrag o, int x[2]);




        bool operator>(const CProstokat & p2); //I have changed it because now I can use 'this->' 
        bool operator<(CProstokat & p2);
        bool operator>=(CProstokat & p2);
        bool operator<=(CProstokat & p2);

        bool operator>(COkrag o2);
        bool operator<(COkrag o2);
        bool operator>=(COkrag o2);
        bool operator<=(COkrag o2);
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream &wy, COkrag &O);

};
#endif


#ifndef __PROSTOKAT_H__
#define __PROSTOKAT_H__
#include "figura.h"


class COkrag;
class CProstokat: public CFigura
{
    protected:
    int m_iSz, m_iWy; 


    public:
        CProstokat();
        CProstokat(int x, int y, int szer, int wys);
        ~CProstokat();
        void ZmienSz(int x);
        void ZmienWy(int y);
        float PodajObwod();
        float PodajPole();
        void operator+(int a);
        friend void operator+(CProstokat p, int x[2]);

        bool operator>(COkrag& o2);
        bool operator<(COkrag& o2);
        bool operator>=(COkrag& o2);
        bool operator<=(COkrag& o2);

        bool operator>(CProstokat p2);
        bool operator<(CProstokat p2);
        bool operator>=(CProstokat p2);
        bool operator<=(CProstokat p2);


        friend ostream& operator << (ostream &wy, CProstokat &P);

};
#endif
```

I hope I understand Your advice correctly. Thank all of you for time spent on answering.

Comment: The Google keyword phrase is "*forward declaration*".

Comment: Also, the common convention is to use English identifiers, not ones in your native language. Similary, that "C" at beginning of class name is irritating most of time and doesn't bring any clarity to your code (every IDE can tell you whether `Circle` is class or anything else, no need for "CCircle" - which makes it even harder to read).

Comment: it is my homework task and teacher requires this type of CClass declaration. But thank You for advice i will use your recommended notation style to my private projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the header files include *each other*. This will result in the following scenario:

Assume some code file includes `procostat.h`. Now when processing `procostat.h` the preprocessor will first process the include guard, defining `__PROKOSTAT_H__` (side node: All identifiers containing double underscores are reserved for the implementation; don't use them for your own code), then include `figura.h`, and then find and process the `#include "okrag.h"`. In processing that file, the same will happen until the `#include "prokostat.h"`, which instructs the compiler to *again* process that file (note that until that point, none of your actual code, except for the contents of `figura.h`, has been processed). While processing (again) that file, it will again first process the include guard, find that `__PROKOSTAT_H__` is already defined, and therefore honor the `#ifndef` by *not* processing the content of the file until the corresponding `#endif` at the end. Then the compiler will continue to process the file `okrag.g` (remember: It still has not seen a single line of actual code from `prokostat.h`!) and come across the friend definition of `operator>` which uses `CProkostat`. But up to now, it *did not see* the definition of `CProkrostat`, therefore it complains about the undefined identifier.

Now how to fix it? Well, the simplest fix is just noticing that `prokostat.h` doesn't actually reference anything from `okostat.h`, therefore you just can remove the `#include "okostat.h"` from it. That will break the circular dependency and therefore fix the immediate problem.

However it's not yet the perfect fix, for two reasons: First, what if you ever need to reference `COkrak` in `prokostat.h`? And second, you'll need to recompile every file including `procostat.h` whenever `okrak.h` changes, even if the file uses nothing from `okrak.h`.

Therefore the correct fix is to not only remove the `#include "okrak.h"` from `prokostat.h` but *additionally* remove the `#include "prokostat.h"` from `okrak.h` and instead add a *forward declaration* for `CProkostat` at the beginning of that file (i.e. before any of its definitions). That forward declaration looks like this:

```
class CProkostat;
```

This lets the compiler know that a class of that name exists without telling any of the details (it's called an incomplete type). You don't need those details to declare the friend function (however you *do* need them to define the friend function, so in the corresponding implementation file you'll have to `#include "prokostat.h"`).

As a side note, your comparison operators should take the objects by const reference, to avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: thank You very much for answer. It is very useful advice for me. I learned new things. Thank for Your time. I'm going back to work and I will post my effects.

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency in includes. You include prostokat.h in okrag.h and the other way round. This way one of the includes will not work( you will get empty file because of `ifndef`).

To solve this add a forward declaration of the class CProstokat at the beginning of okrag.h:

```
class CProstokat;
```

Also, change signatures of your operators to get arguments by const references instead of getting them by values. This will both improve performance and facilitate using forward declaration.

Comment: He will also need to use const refs as parameters to the comparison operators, otherwise the forward declarations won't work.

Comment: Alternatively you can make a bigger change in the code (but this seems to be the proper way to do it) and implement comparison operator between CFigura, which will work for both COkrag and CProstokat.

Comment: yes it would be good solution but i need to compare features avaiable only in children classes. I will try first test your advices and then i appeal again

Comment: Then implement virtual methods in children classes that will provide values to compare in the base class.